# WPF - Populate TreeView From SQL

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, treeview

I have a list of homes in a database that I am attempting to populate a TreeView from and I can not seem to grasp how to do it. Coming from win forms this was pretty simple and straight forward. However, this conversion does not seem to be as easy to understand.

In Win Forms I would query the DB, return all the rows into a datatable, then dump that datatable into the Tree. While dumping I would also match the ID of the row to call upon later.

**Database**

```
ID - House - Rooms - Bathrooms - Fence - Status
1   House 1    3         2         Y       FS
2   House 2    2         1         N       FS
3   House 3    1         1         Y        S
4   House 4    4         3         Y        S
```

**Desired Tree View**

- For Sale

  - House 1

    - Rooms 3
    - Bathrooms
    - Fence
  - House 2

    - Rooms 2
    - Bathrooms 1
    - No Fence
- Sold

  - House 3

    - Rooms 1
    - Bathrooms 1
    - Fence
  - House 4

    - Rooms 4
    - Bathrooms 3
    - Fence

**Old Win Forms Code**

```
' Add Homes to tree
    Dim houseList As DataTable = DBQuery()
    For Each home As DataRow In houseList.Rows

        Dim MyNode() As TreeNode
        MyNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find("Homes", True)
        MyNode(0).Nodes.Add(home.Item("ID"), home.Item("House")).Nodes.Add(home.Item("Rooms"))

    Next home
```

Unfortunately everything I've found was in C# and not VB. Attempting to convert the examples were pretty hard to follow to continue to mold.

I've attempted to use follow these two links, but to no avail I was not able to succeed. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF

Thanks for any help or pointers provided!

Comment: Show the code you've tried and where you think it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would appear you are just not aware of the new properties in WPF.

TreeViews now use Items instead of nodes.
The Header property is the text.

Use my image below to help, it's fairly simple so can be expanded, any further questions let me know.

[image: My Working Code]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for... I'll give it a go tonight and report back on the results.

Comment: No worries, if it solved it for you, please mark as anwser :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you again!